# Change the terminal-character size (with python)

Tags: python, linux, windows, terminal

I am trying to draw shapes in the python terminal but because letters are taller than wide, everything is distorted/stretched. Is there way to change the (don't know how it's called) cell size to something square like 10x10px? I wouldn't care if the actual characters are distorted (for example "H" being squashed together). I work in both Linux and Windows. I have added an example of what I mean. The coordinates of the square are generated with:

```
def getCPoints(x,y,r,steps):
    coords = []
    for n in range(steps):
        coords.append(((x + r * math.cos(2 * math.pi * (n / steps))),y + r * math.sin(2 * math.pi * (n / steps))))
    return coords
```

[image: Not-so-round circle]

Comment: Change cmd font to [monospaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font)

Comment: Is that possible from python?